# Installing gevent on Mavericks (Enthought Canopy python)

Tags: python-2.7, osx-mavericks, gevent, canopy

Has anyone had any luck building gevent 1.0 in Mavericks?

I've tried the following:

1. pip (as recommended on the [gevent package index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent#downloads))
2. easy_install
3. compiling from source

I keep getting the same error when building 'gevent.core':

```
...
building 'gevent.core' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-i386-2.7/gevent
Compiling with an SDK that doesn't seem to exist: /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk
Please check your Xcode installation
gcc -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -U__llvm__ -      
DLIBEV_EMBED=1 -DEV_COMMON= -DEV_CHECK_ENABLE=0 -DEV_CLEANUP_ENABLE=0 -DEV_EMBED_ENABLE=0 
-DEV_PERIODIC_ENABLE=0 -Ibuild/temp.macosx-10.6-i386-2.7/libev -Ilibev -  
I/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.2.0.1610.macosx-
x86/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7 -c gevent/gevent.core.c -o build/temp.macosx-
10.6-i386-2.7/gevent/gevent.core.o
clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk'
In file included from gevent/gevent.core.c:17:
/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.2.0.1610.macosx- 
x86/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7/Python.h:33:10: fatal error: 
  'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Seems to be a problem with XCode. I made sure I have the XCode (v. 5.0.2) command line tools installed with:

```
xcode-select --install
```

But that didn't seem to change anything. Apparently I'm not alone with this problem ([a missing /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178686/compiling-with-an-sdk-that-doesnt-seem-to-exist-developer-sdks-macosx10-6-sdk)), but I'd like to stick with Enthought's Canopy version of python if I can (and have already spent too much time combing the Apple Developer site to try download MacOSX10.6.sdk directly).

Any suggestions that don't involve starting over with a macport'ed python? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, Apple pulled a fast one on the latest XCode, such that `gcc` is no longer actually gcc, but is symlinked to clang, which is not compatible with standard Pythons, including Canopy's.

It should work better if you install Xcode 3.2.1 Developer Tools from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. 3.1.2 Developer Tools had the MacOSX10.5.sdk, but I was able to successful install gevent after downloading **3.2.1** Developer Tools (and the MacOSX10.6.sdk).

Comment: Thanks, corrected my comment for the record, to reflect your experience.

Answer (score 0):

For me the hint on gevent website helped:

pip install cython git+git://github.com/gevent/gevent.git#egg=gevent